# Presto - UNION Varchar and Integer data types

Tags: union, presto

I need to create a view in Presto by combining the data from two tables . Some column data types are not matching between tables and its failing the query. When i run the queries individually they work fine but after adding UNION it fails .Would appreciate some guidance to resolve the issue

new_sales.opportunities  - margin_bps is double
old_sales.opportunities - margin_bps is string

select
coalesce(margin_bps,0)
from new_sales.opportunities
UNION
select
coalesce(try_cast(margin_bps as double),0) as margin_bps
from old_sales.opportunities

Error : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: io.prestosql.spi.type.DoubleType

Comment: What version of Presto are you running? Can you post the schema of your tables and the full stacktrace of the error, too?

Comment: Hi Martin - Thanks for your response. After analysis, i found out its because of  some data issue in the data files used by the schema. For this specific attribute, data type was string prior to June-2020 but after June it was changed to double. So, we have some data files with string as data type and some with double data type. Due to this data type inconsistency, the query is failing